# Maximum distance of visible objects in p5.js WebGL

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I want have some very large objects present on canvas, but there seems to be a distance limit of about 2000 and anything further is not visible at all.

Is there a way to disable this option or reassign the border value?

I couldn't find any mention in any documentation.

In the picture I am almost in the center of a ball with radius 4000 and the grey circle in the middle grows or shrinks based on me zooming in or out.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be experiencing [camera clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(computer_graphics)): geometry that gets cuts off when it's to close (near clipping plane) or too far (far clipping plane) from the view frustum (imagine the base section of a pyramid with the center of the camera as the tip).

[image: view frustum]

(Image credits: [MithrandirMage - Own work This W3C-unspecified vector image was created with Inkscape.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(computer_graphics)#/media/File:ViewFrustum.svg))

You can play with the [`frustum()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frustum) or [`perspective()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/perspective) methods to adjust the near/far clipping distance: which ever makes more sense for your setup